# Handle the state of IKEv2 Personal VPN with Swift

Tags: swift, vpn

I've implemented the possibility of opening VPN connection with IKEv2. The connection works great after I close (kill) the app. However, I want to get the current connection status after I launch the app again. How can I do that?
Unfortunately this returns `invalid` status when I try to call:

```
NEVPNManager.shared().connection.status
```

but I see (and it's correct and it's true) Personal VPN in active state here:

[image]

Could you provide how to get actual status of my Personal VPN?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this case with this implementation specially for IKEv2

```
// special case for IKEv2
NEVPNManager.shared().loadFromPreferences { error in
    if error != nil {
        //
    } else {
        print(NEVPNManager.shared().connection.status)
    }
}
```

I've added this into my connection manager and now the app handles correctly the status of Personal VPN after relaunch of the app